# Is there an each_if in ruby?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, each

Let's say I have this each loop in Ruby.

```
@list.each { |i|
  puts i

  if i > 10
    break
  end
}
```

Where I want to loop through the list until a condition is met.

This stung me as "un Ruby'ish" and since I'm new to Ruby, is there a Ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#detect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001485) or [`Enumerable#take_while`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001519), depending on the result you want.

```
@list.detect { |i|
  puts i
  i > 10
} # Returns the first element greater than 10, or nil.
```

As others have noted, a better style would be to first make your sub-selection and then act on it, e.g.:

```
@list.take_while{ |i| i <= 10 }.each{|i| puts i}
```

Comment: Maybe I am too orthodox, but I'd feel a bit uneasy using "take_while" or "detect", which are meant to be used functionally (they return something), to have some side effects. That said, they do what the OP asked for.So maybe: @list.take_while { ... }.each. [edit] ok, that's mattexx answer.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but do you usually indent your Ruby code with four spaces? Nevermind: noticed that the OP was doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could use take_while:

```
@list.take_while { |i| i <= 11 }.each { |i| puts i }
```

Comment: but this way you'd be iterating twice. Is there a way to pass a condition to an `each`, and then only execute the block on the elements which match the condition?